How to arrange 3 pictures in a figure, one picture on the left, and on the right side one picture each at the top and bottom?
I am trying to align 3 pictures like this using minipage:

But my output looks like this:

This is my code which uses \sidesubfloat to generate the labels at the top left:
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}       
\usepackage{floatrow}       
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=8cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-9x16.jpg}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3.8cm]{example-image-16x9}}\\
    
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=3.8cm]{example-image-16x9}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Why is the total height of the right minipage larger than of the left side?

Is your complaint that there is too much space between (b) and (c)?  If so, why do you have the \vspace as well as the blank line causing the paragraph break?

@Teepeemm yes that's exactly my issue. Do you mean I should remove the blank line as well as the \ (otherwise there is no space at all)? It still looks a few pixels off, but it's fine.

If your complaint is too much vertical space, then the first step is to remove the extra vertical space.  I would try \\[\baselineskip] after the (b) image if you want some space.

Floatrow may not pay any attention to normal spacing mechanics (it uses a picture environment and \put (x,y)).
\caption puts the baseline at the very top, hense valign=T.
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newcommand{\sidecaption}[1][\empty]% #1 = label name (optional)
{\begin{subfigure}[t]{1.6em}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, skip=0pt}%
  \caption{}
  \ifx\empty#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi
\end{subfigure}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\sidecaption \includegraphics[height=8cm,keepaspectratio,valign=T]{example-image-9x16.jpg}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][8cm][t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \sidecaption \includegraphics[height=3.8cm,valign=T]{example-image-16x9}\par
    \vfill
    \sidecaption \includegraphics[height=3.8cm,valign=T]{example-image-16x9}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

