Rearrange subtables side-by-side, by using table and tblr
I have the following table, created with table and tblr:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{
}
\subcaption{first}
\begin{tblr}
{
   width = \textwidth, 
   colspec = {lllllll}, 
   hlines,
}
1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
\end{tblr}
\bigskip
\subcaption{second}
\begin{tblr}
{
   width = \textwidth, 
   colspec = {lllllll}, 
   hlines,
}
9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
\end{tblr}
\bigskip
\subcaption{third}
\begin{tblr}
{
   width = \textwidth, 
   colspec = {lllllll}, 
   hlines,
}
6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
\end{tblr}
\bigskip
\subcaption{fourth}
\begin{tblr}
{
   width = \textwidth, 
   colspec = {lllllll}, 
   hlines,
}
0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}


\end{document}

Which gives me the following output:

However, I would like to put side-by-side the subtables as follows:

How can I do it with \table and \tblr ?

IMHO using option width=\textwidth for tables, that should not use the while width of the textarea is not the best idea …

Additionally I would use e.g. subcaptionblock or \subcaptionbox or subtable and remove the \bigskip (because is also adds a new paragraph).

Thanks a lot @cabohah!

You seem to want \subcaptionbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Caption text}

\subcaptionbox{first}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
%    width = 0.4\textwidth, 
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
  1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}\hspace{4em}%
\subcaptionbox{second}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
%    width = 0.4\textwidth, 
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
  9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}

\bigskip

\subcaptionbox{third}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
%    width = 0.4\textwidth, 
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
  6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}\hspace{4em}%
\subcaptionbox{fourth}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
%    width = 0.4\textwidth, 
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
  0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}

\end{table}

\end{document}


I wouldn't use the “vertical” order, but you can get it with some low level tricks.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Caption text}

\tabskip=2em
\valign{&\hbox{#}\cr
\subcaptionbox{first}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
  1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}&
\subcaptionbox{second}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
  9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}
\cr\noalign{\hspace{4em}}
\subcaptionbox{third}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
  6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}&
\subcaptionbox{fourth}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lllllll}, 
    hlines,
  }
  0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
  0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
  \end{tblr}%
}
\cr}

\end{table}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot! Just a silly question... Is there a simple option of \subcaptionbox to put (a) and (b) on the left (with (b) under (a)) and (c) and (d) on the right (with (d)  under (c))?

@Ommo No, but, unless you're using a “top-down” language, people read from left to right (or right to left, of course).

@Ommo I added a way to get the “wrong” ordering.

You can put the captions in their own subtables beside the tabulars.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724035/how-to-arrange-3-pictures-in-a-figure-one-picture-on-the-left-and-on-the-right/724047?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#724047 for example.

Amazing, thanks a lot! This is great!

Like this?

With use of subcaption package and tblr for placement od sub figures (in correct order), the code can be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Table caption}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[c] X[c]  @{}} }
    \subfloat[first]{
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{7}{l}}, 
                 hlines}
    1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
    1 & 2  & 2  & 1  & 7  & 5  & 9 \\
    \end{tblr}
                    }
        &   \subfloat[second]{   
            \begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{7}{l}}, 
                         hlines}
        9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
        9 & 5  & 7  & 0  & 5  & 4  & 8 \\
            \end{tblr}
                    }    \\[5mm]
    \subfloat[third]{
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{7}{l}}, 
                 hlines}    
    6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
    6 & 5  & 1  & 5  & 2  & 3  & 0 \\
    \end{tblr}
                    }
        &   \subfloat[fourth]{   
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{7}{l}}, 
                 hlines}    
    0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
    0 & 6  & 7  & 1  & 1  & 0  & 1 \\
    \end{tblr}  
                    }
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


Thanks a lot @Zarko! It is a great solution as well!
