Standard way of subfigure labelling
When I use the APS template (such as revtex4-2), it provides only default figure styles but not subfigure styles. If I add subfigures into one figure, they would be labeled on the bottom of each subfigure. However, the more "standard" way of labelling subfigures should be at the upper-left corner of the subfigures. Is there a standard way of using LaTeX to do this? Currently, professors that I know all use PowerPoint to compose subfigures into one figure, but I think this solution is ugly as it is not LaTeX based.

if you need to use the template for submission and it doesn't support subfigures, it may be that subfigures are not welcome in submissions. but please provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem. insofar as there is a 'standard' approach, it probably puts the subfigure captions at the bottom, just like figure captions. use of powerpoint sounds bizarre, but I've never used it so my opinion's not worth anything.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724035/how-to-arrange-3-pictures-in-a-figure-one-picture-on-the-left-and-on-the-right
